# How do I stop django from prompting to create superuser during tests?

Tags: python, django, testing

When I run tests, Django is always asking:

*You have installed Django's auth system, and don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):*

I dont want to create it. I dont want Django to ask.
The obvious action to do is remove `'django.contrib.auth',` from `INSTALLED_APPS`. But I cant because I need it to my set of tests.
Im using **sqlite3** as DB.

**EDIT:**

A little example of one of my tests as requested.

```
class RegisterBusinessTests(TestCase):
    url = 'business:new_business'

    def test_upload_business(self):
        login_user(self)
        post_content = get_business_post_content()
        response = http_request_post(self, post_content, url=self.url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        assert_object_exists('business.Business', 'name', post_content['name'])
```

Comment: What kind of tests are you doing?

Comment: Unit test. Im using TestCase.

Comment: Can you please add your code here?

Comment: Are you using django's testing (i.e. via `manage.py test`)?

Comment: Yes I am. `manage.py test app`.